# PHP script on AWS EC2 NGINX not working but download

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up my site in AWS ec2 using nginx. Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

autoindex off;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/myproject;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    #location / {
    #}

    location = /index.php {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/index.php break;
    }

    location / {
      if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app/index.php break;
      }
    }

    location ~ \.(secret|salt|engine|inc|po|sh|bat|cmd|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|inc)$ {
      deny all;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri =404
        root           /usr/share/nginx/myproject;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

When I access the public DNS, I got download instead of running the PHP script. Is there any problem in my nginx config?

Answer (score 1):

Your `rewrite...break` statements should be `rewrite...last` as the PHP file needs to be processed in a different location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^ /app/index.php last;
    }
}
```

However, the above functionality is usually implemented as:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.php;
}
```

---

Other issues include:

- a missing `;` in the `location ~ \.php$` block following the `try_files` statement.
- the `root` statement in the `location ~ \.php$` block should be deleted, as it is unnecessary.